# What does check condition in programme in php

Tags: php

Actually I have made small programme in php using simple array and search name from array and my programe given below :

```
$n = array("Akki","Amesh","Akit","Baa","aaakk");

$hint = "";

$find = "ak";

if ($find !== "") {

    $find = strtolower($find);

    $lwn = strlen($find);

    foreach($n as $gt){     
        if(stristr($find, substr($gt,0,$lwn))){
            if($hint === ''){                   
                $hint .= $gt;
            }else{          
                $hint .= ",$gt";
            }
            }
    }
}
echo ($hint == "") ? "NNN" : $hint ;
```

My query how to check $hint got data are single & double and how to add comma after got name from array

Like I have searched name using word ak and i got two name Akki and Akit.
and its perfect but i want to know how to add comma between that name.

And What does check this condition :  ($hint === '')

tell me if anyone know my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this code does:

```
        if($hint === ''){                   
            $hint .= $gt;
        }else{          
            $hint .= ",$gt";
        }
```

is see if $hint is empty (which it will be the first time the preceding if condition is true, since it is initialized to empty at the beginning).  This is used to add a comma only if there is already a value in $hint.  The === operator simply compares value and type as opposed to only value comparison when using ==.  It is really not necessary here.

Does that answer your question?

EDIT: Regarding the comma, as far as I can see the comma is added currently. The code has potential for improvement, but works.

Comment: Yes this is a perfect answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help out with an easier solution:

```
$hint = implode(", ", preg_grep("/^$find/i", $n));
```

- Grep your array for the following and return matches:

  - Look at the start of the string `^` for `$find` case-insensitive `i`
- Join on a comma `,`

Answer (score 0):

To add comma change your else condition :

```
else{          
                $hint .= ","."$gt";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

your if condition: `if($hint === ''){` will check for `$hint`'s value and datatype as well. if datatype matches then it will check for the value.

so in your case it will check for `string` datatype and then compare with `$hint`'s value i.e. blank string.

Also as mentioned in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44808960/6592263) you should use `implode` function.

Comment: you can read more about difference b/w `===` and `==` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp